# How can I use call a stored procedure within SAS without using ProcSQL?

Tags: stored-procedures, sas

At my Co-Op my manager is asking me to take my SAS output tables that I've gathered and then to execute a stored procedure that will upload and update any data that has changed into an online KPI(Key Performance Indicators) excel sheet.

Apparently my boss isn't too sure of how to do this even and he's been programming for quite some time.

In laymen's terms this is what I need to do:

- create a  table of gathered KPI's (Done)
- Send the table to the Stored Procedure  (I don't want to use ProcSQL in SAS 9.3 because I would be hardcoding in too many fields)
- Have the Stored procedure read into the online datasheet (done)
- Replace KPI's if they have changed (done)

Here is the ProcSQL that I have figured: Ambiguous names have been given to keep anominity:

```
%let id  = 'HorseRaddish';
%let pwd = 'ABC321';


proc sql;
    connect to odbc (dsn='JerrySeinfeld' uid=&id pwd=&pwd);
    execute (spKPIInsertUpdateKPIData '411', '7.2', '8808', 'M', 'NANANA', 'WorkStation', 'Testing1212', '1', '8/3/2013 10:42AM')  by odbc;
   disconnect from odbc;
quit;

run;
```

Above code works fine, but like I said it's a pain to hard code in KPI calues for hundreds of fields.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, and I had flexibility to do so, I would rewrite the SP to pull the parameters from a table and upload the table, then call the SP.  That's got to be faster.

If it's not, you can script that SP line fairly easily.  You will still run it in PROC SQL, but you don't have to write it out by hand.

Something like:

```
proc sql;
select cats("execute(spKPIInsertUdateKPIData '",var1,"''",var2,"','",var3,<... more ...>,"') by odbc") into :execlist separated by ';';
quit;
```

That creates a macro variable &execlist that contains the calls to the SP.  Then you just do

```
proc sql;
connect to odbc ... ;
&execlist.
disconnect from odbc;
quit;
```

That does have some length limits, you might have to do it a bit differently (either cut it up or use `%include`) if you are over ~20k characters.

But again, this is probably not a very good way to do this - better is load to table and have the SP update from that table.  Something like:

```
libname sqldb oledb init_string=whatever;
proc sql;
drop table sqldb._tempSP_KPI;
create table sqldb._tempSP_KPI as select * from <dataset containing values>;
connect to oledb (init_string=whatever);
<exec SP that uses the _tempSP_KPI table)>
quit;

quit;
```